# calcHist method - Invalid Arguments

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to find histogram in the image and I am trying to use calcHist method like below

```
calcHist( &bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
```

I am trying this [example from this link.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html) 
All the time I am getting this error and I am not able to compile the code

```
"Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void calcHist(const cv::Mat *, int, const int *, const cv::_InputArray &, cv::SparseMat &, int, const int *, const float * *, bool, bool) void calcHist(const cv::Mat *, int, const int *, const cv::_InputArray &, const cv::_OutputArray &, int, const int *, const float * *, bool, bool) void calcHist(const cv::_InputArray &, const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &, const cv::_InputArray &, const cv::_OutputArray &, const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &, const std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>> &, bool) '"
```

I have configured my build C/C++ build path with the required includes

I am working on 32 bit system and have set up appropriate NDK for windows 32 bit system. Same code when I run on 64 bit system where the method compiles without any issue!

Really Banging my head since morning . Someone please help!

```
Mat imagMat=cvLoadImageM("/sdcard/ImageProcessing/TestImage.png");
LOGD("Number Of Rows = %d",imagMat.rows);

/// Separate the image in 3 places ( B, G and R )
vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
split( imagMat, bgr_planes );

/// Establish the number of bins
int histSize = 256;

/// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;
const float* histRange = { range };

bool uniform = true;

bool accumulate = false;

Mat b_hist, g_hist, r_hist;

const int* channel=0;

calcHist( &bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
```

Thanks in Advance.

NSM

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest trying histSize as an array of ints not an int. I know you only have one plane but I think the call is really expecting an array - one for each plane. Try creating an array of length 1 with 256 as the only element.